# Cloning an item with js and the increment sign (++), my error with double increment i

Tags: javascript, html, clone, increment

Here's my problem:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    const adduser = document.querySelector("#add-user");
    const original = document.querySelectorAll('#input');
    let i = 0;

    function duplicate() {
        
        let clone = original[0].cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "input" + ++i;
        clone.name = "input" + ++i;
        
        original[0].after(clone);
    }

    adduser.onclick = function() {

        duplicate();

    };
});
```

```html
<form action="second.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Name of the user:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control multinput" class="username" id="input" placeholder="Enter the user's name" name="fullName">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add-user">+ Add a user</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you've already guessed, I'm trying to clone a field, but I want to increment two properties of this very field (in this case, that's an input field).

Now my problem is that, as soon as I push the button to clone the INPUT, in this case, I will increment both the id and the name, but unfortunately, they won't stay the same number, in fact the markup will become:

```
<form action="second.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Name of the user:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control multinput" id="input" placeholder="Enter the user's name" name="fullName">
        <input type="text" class="form-control multinput" id="input" placeholder="Enter the user's name" name="input3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control multinput" id="input" placeholder="Enter the user's name" name="input1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add-user">+ Add a user</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

this one. As you can notice, we have two wrong actions, in my option, which are:

1. The input cloned and then attached to the original input have the wrong order because is added to the very first element (0) so the last element attached won't be ascendant, but in this case, it will have the higher number.
2. Both the id and the name will be incremented, so I will have the same input with the id=1 and the name=2, which is not ideal.

Any hint on how to fix the problem?

Comment: `++i` increments `i`. If you just wanted the value of `i` without incrementing it again, you would instead write…?

Comment: i.. but I need to increment the value on I on both!

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice each time `duplicate` function is called.

Comment: @MarcoMaffei - But once you've done `++i`, `i` has the **updated** value. So `clone.id = "input" + ++i;` updates it and assigns (say) `"input1"` to `id`. Then `clone.name = "update" + i;` (no increment) will also assign `"input1"` to `name`. Or do it in one statement: `clone.id = clone.name = "input" + ++i;` Or for max clarity: `++i; clone.id = clone.name = "input" + i;`

Comment: You can assign both properties with one increment: `clone.id = clone.name = "input" + i;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment `i` only *once*, before you assign the new `id` and `name`. Also, use `insertAdjacentElement` on the button to insert each new input before it, rather than `after`, to insert the new input:

```
  function duplicate() {
    i++;
    let clone = original[0].cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "input" + i;
    clone.name = "input" + i;
    document.querySelector('button').insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', clone);
  }
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const adduser = document.querySelector("#add-user");
  const original = document.querySelectorAll('#input');
  let i = 0;

  function duplicate() {
    i++;
    let clone = original[0].cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "input" + i;
    clone.name = "input" + i;
    document.querySelector('button').insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', clone);
  }

  adduser.onclick = duplicate
});
```

```html
<form action="second.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Name of the user:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control multinput" class="username" id="input" placeholder="Enter the user's name" name="fullName">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add-user">+ Add a user</button>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <!-- <input type="button" name="next" value="submit"> -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What about adding a counter to limit the clone function?

Comment: Looks like you already have a counter with the `i` variable, so you can check that. In `duplicate`, do: `if (i > 10) return alert('You already have 10 users!');` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- Increment i after using it, not each time you need it or it will incremented multiple times instead of 1 every duplication
- use setAttribute
- append to the parent element, not after the original input to achieve descending order

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    const adduser = document.querySelector("#add-user");
    const original = document.getElementById('input');
    let i = 1;

    function duplicate() {
        
        let clone = original.cloneNode(true);
        clone.setAttribute("id", "input"+i);
        clone.setAttribute("name", "input"+i);
        i++
        
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }

    adduser.onclick = function() {

        duplicate();

    };
});
```

```html
<form action="second.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Name of the user:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control multinput" class="username" id="input" placeholder="Enter the user's name" name="fullName">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add-user">+ Add a user</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why would I use `setAttribute()` for properties?

Comment: It is going to attach the other input to the button, not to the field..

Comment: WHat about setting a limit for the clone action?